# Ckan, Redis & Duplicate Datasets

Tags: ckan

We have 100+ harvests running through Redis and we see there is a downtime /Latency in harvesting Datasets from various sources. One more problem Harvesting through Redis is creating a lot of Duplicate Datasets. We are using CKAN 2.3 on Ubuntu 14.4 & Postgres 9.3

Comment: It would be helpful if you can format your question according to MVCE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please also provide the types of your harvest sources (e.g. CKAN, socrata, data.json etc) and ideally the harvest log.